# EXCEL - How To Count The Number of Digits In a Cell

Tags: excel-formula

Could anyone enlighten me on how to count the number of digits (numbers) in a cell in Excel?

I have tried LEN and SUBSTITUTE and could not get it to work..

For example a cell has a mix of text and numbers: b72a037h, the formula would take into account 7,2,0,3,7 and return 5.

Is it possible to create such a formula?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Helcome to Stackoverflow. When the answer below solves your problem you should accept it (look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to remove all digits one by one using `SUBSTITUTE`, and then compare the resulting length against the original length.  The difference would give the number of digits:

```
=LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(48), ""), CHAR(49), ""), CHAR(50), ""),
    CHAR(51), ""), CHAR(52), ""), CHAR(53), ""), CHAR(54), ""), CHAR(55), ""), CHAR(56), ""),
    CHAR(57), ""))
```

Comment: This approach makes total sense and it works! What a bright idea thanks a bunch Tim!

Answer (score 3):

Or try this array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

```
=COUNT(-MID(A1,ROW($1:$99),1))
```

Comment: Have you enter the formula by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER ?